# How should I reference OS specific folders in docker compose?

Tags: windows, docker, macos, docker-compose

In docker compose files we can have volumes with the path to local folders. Mac and windows of course have different user home directories. I am distributing the compose to people different OS. What is the best way to reference a users home folder so we dont have to change all the volume mounts every time?

```
volumes:
  - ~/.ssh:~/.ssh     (mac/linux)
  - C:/Users/myuser/.ssh:~/.ssh      (windows)
```

Is there any way to define properties based on OS (similar to maven)? Something like this:

```
properties:
  - home_folder: OS == windows? '%HOMEPATH%' : '~'
volumes:
  - ${home_folder}/.ssh:~/.ssh
```

Comment: Does Windows provide you with a `$HOME` environment variable? Never mind, [looks like it does not](https://superuser.com/questions/607105/is-the-home-environment-variable-normally-set-in-windows).

Comment: This seems like a case where it'd be easier to run the program outside of Docker, so that you can use normal filesystem access – Docker's filesystem isolation features are getting in your way, which might make it the wrong tool.

Comment: Have you tried `$HOME/.ssh:/root/.ssh` on both Windows and Linux ?

Comment: David there are a many reasons I am using docker. Saying not to use docker because I cant find a clean solution to this very minor issue is just plain silly. Philippe/larsks - thanks for the replies. Windows doesnt have $HOME variable. In fact windows uses %ENV_VAR% syntax so I couldn't even create a $HOME environment variable and have it run the same way as linux/mac =(. Is there any way to pass a variable into the docker-compose up command and have the compose.yml use that in the volume path?

Comment: Windows uses % rather than $ for variables :(

Comment: Windows uses %, but $HOME should work in docker-compose.yml.

Comment: ah great will try and post back in a bit

Comment: Dude ... you are brilliant. Docker compose does read the variables on windows if I put $HOME. So I can distrubute one compose.cmd which has 'SET HOME=%HOMEPATH%' and a compose.sh which has 'EXPORT HOME=~'. The compose file can reference it as $HOME/.ssh . I will have a coworker test it on mac next week but thinking its going to work! Its actually a pretty clean solution. If you post an answer I will accept it as the solution.

Comment: Another recommendation would be to use a `*nix-like` environment like `git-bash` or `cygwin`, so you don't need `compose.cmd`, just maintain a single script `compose.sh`.

Comment: probably true but what Im trying to do is to try to enable 30+ developers to use docker images I created. Any extra step is an email to me asking what is not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even though Windows uses `%...%` for environment variables, `docker-compose.yml` recognize `$HOME` notation.

You just need to run :

```
SET HOME=%HOMEPATH%
```

before running `docker-compose up`

Comment: sadly I found one issue. it works if I run the script from command line but if I use docker desktop to restart the containers the variable is not set. I suppose for windows I need to set the environment variable directly in advanced settings manually. For mac I assume there is some .bash_rc or .bash_profile where it can be set